# Registered at GoDaddy with NameSilo DNS

Tags: networking, dns, web-hosting, domain-name, nameservers

If domain.tld is registered at GoDaddy and its default GoDaddy nameservers are changed to use NameSilo's nameservers, is it possible to manage domain.tld's dns at NameSilo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you changed the DNS servers, you may update DNS records on the side of Namesilo.

Just keep in mind this tip: your DNS records are managed on the side of DNS servers. If your domain name is pointed to GD's default nameservers, then you may update the records in the account with GoDaddy. If the domain name is delegated to the DNS servers of Namesilo - then in the account with them.

Also, depending on whether you have a hosting package or not, you may manage DNS records either in the account itself or in cPanel.

Normally, if you purchase a cPanel based hosting, you may update DNS settings in 'DNS Manager' (aka Domain Name Zone File) of your cPanel.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. However, after setting NameSilo's nameservers for my GoDaddy registered domain, in NameSilo the domain did not magically appear in some management space or place to enter it in some NameSilo management space, to control the zone's properties. BTW, anyone ever tell you you have a classic Mona Lisa smile?

Comment: @guessed Ha! No one, actually. Thanks! :)
This totally makes sense, since normally it's not enough to point the domain name to nameservers, you also need to add it to your hosting cPanel, i.e. at the end of Namesilo. Check with Namesilo, if your purchased plan has cPanel. If so, you will need to add the domain name (their support team should be able to do so for you) and then you may find domain zone file as described here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Edit+DNS+Zone

Answer (score 0):

Registrars usually do not provide DNS for domains not registered with them. So if you have the domain at Godaddy, you need to use Godaddy NS (domaincontrol) or find a nameserver provider like Cloudflare. Exception is when you do hosting, in that case you can use registrar's NS for domains not registered with them.